# Question on binary relationship.

Tags: self-learning, binary, economics, binary-operations

Condition A:

Given x, y in X such that $yRx$ then it follows that

$\lambda y +(1-\lambda)xRx$ for all $0< \lambda<1$

Condition B:

Given x, y in X such that $yPx$ then it follows that

$\lambda y +(1-\lambda)xPx$ for all $0< \lambda<1$

Show that the condition B implies the condition A.

R refers a weak preference relation and P is a strict preference relation.

---

I don’t understand how to show this implication.

What do you think? How can I show this? I am very confused.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I agree that the relations are identical, with just different names for the same condition. One of the variables $y$ is in a different font in one place ...

Comment: Yeah, they look the same. Is this from a book? Is there errata/corrections you can check?

Comment: This is just the condition for convexity.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Sorry there is a foot note. R refers a weak preference relation and P is a strict preference relation. but I cannot show this again.

Comment: @ShawSa Sorry there is a foot note. R refers a weak preference relation and P is a strict preference relation. how can I show it?

Comment: @EthanBolker Sorry there is a foot note. R refers a weak preference relation and P is a strict preference relation.

Comment: The only possible issue: change your book, throw this one in the bin! :-) It is really too unclear.

Comment: What is a preference relation? You should give us that too.

Comment: It may be that strict preference always implies weak preference, like in algebra strict inequality $(>)$ implies weak inequality (\ge).

Comment: A weak preference is usually of the form $x\ge y$ and a strong preference is of the form $x\gt y$. This makes sense because a strong preference would imply a weak preference. See the definitions at [this site](https://www.owlnet.rice.edu/~econ370/gilbert/notes/preferences). There are no  inequalities on your page. Is this defined elsewhere in your book?

Comment: @coffeemath yes you are right. I know this Practically. But how can I show this as given in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A counterexample?

Suppose that $yPx$ iff $x=0$ and $y\ne 0$. Unless I'm missing something, $P$ is asymmetric and negatively transitive and a strict preference relation according to [these slides](https://www.epicenter.name/bach/Preferences.pdf). Moreover it satisfies condition B.

The associated weak preference relation $yRx$ iff $\neg xPy$, i.e. if $x=0$ or $y\ne 0$. Now $-1\,R\, 1$ but $\neg0\,R\,1$. Since $0=1/2*-1+1/2*1$ it would seem that condition A does not hold.